# Match between two strings + concatenate

Tags: regex

I have this text:

```
2015-10-01 15:15:30 subject: Announcement: [Word To Find] Some other thext
```

My Goal is to match the date with the time:

```
(?s)(?<=^)(.+?)(?= subject\: Announcement\: )
```

And also the text within `[ ]`

```
(?s)(?<=\[)(.+?)(?=\])
```

How to get those two results in a single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex alternation operator.

```
^(?s).*?(?= subject\: Announcement\: )|(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hU2iZ3/3)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to chime in with a working regex, which although similar to other answers, has all redundancies removed:

```
^(?s)(.*?) subject: Announcement: \[(.*?)]
```

Which yields groups:

```
1. "2015-10-01 15:15:30"
2. "Word To Find"
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/P4MvsHyyxp).

Redundancies:

- It is not necessary to escape `]` except within a character class
- It is never necessary to escape a colon `:`
- The look behind `(?<=^)` is identical to simply `^`, since both are zero-width assertions

Comment: Shouldn't the `]` be escaped? It should match the literal `]`.

Comment: @maroun no, `]` *is* a literal `]`.  As per my answer, the only time you need to escape is when in a character class (obviously, otherwise you'd close the character class), eg to have a class with all brackets: `[()[\]{}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex for that:

```
(.*)\s+subject.*\[(.*?)\]
```

Or

```
(.*)\s+subject.*\[([^]]+)\]
```

The first group contains the date, the second contains the text within the [ ].

Comment: @Miloš You're not capturing it, so not problem. What language are you using?

Comment: Then you can easily extract only matching parts, without complicating the regex :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex to get both match :

```
(?<=^|\[)(.*?)(?=subject|\])
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r/hU2iZ3/2

Note that all you need is use a logical OR (`|`) between your precede tokens and next tokens.

Also note that if your have another brackets within your text you should use a negated character class instead `.*`:

```
(?<=^|\[)([^[\]]*?)(?=subject|\])
```